# Get exact line number on console warning with React Devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

I'm trying to clean the warnings on my app, but I can't find the line numbers when this occurs (it's a big app), it would be useful if after each *'at span'* for example I get the line number as well.

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
    at span
    at span
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Row (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:378674:5)
    at div
    at Table (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:6261:76)
    at div
    at Dash (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:3988:77)
    at Route (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:349007:29)
    at div
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:49290:70)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:48997:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:49310:5)
    at wrappedRoutes
    at Route (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:349007:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:349209:29)
    at main
    at div
    at div
    at MainWrapper (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:298:1)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:346055:68)
    at C (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:349264:37)
    at Router
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:348642:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:348263:35)
    at App (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:179:5)
    at Serice (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:29224:77)
    at Provider (http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js:345767:20)
    at LogIn
```

Comment: This looks like the built version. Run the dev version instead and you will get the exact source file and line number.

Comment: it's dev version, I'm using react-dev-tools

Comment: It says bundle.js though? Which is in `static`? So the above error occurs in the built version, not the development version which you test using `npm start` I don't even see what React devtools has to do with this? It's a browser extension used to inspect the component tree; the above console warning should be produced by your app even without them.